# tr index by clicking td in angularjs without jquery

Tags: angularjs

I have a table, when I click `<td>` I need to return this td name and row index. But if I make this like `ng-click="showIndex(field.name, $index)"` it return index of td, not tr (It's logical I know:) ). I found some way to check parent index, but it's jquery, perhaps there is a way to check it in angular? [I have some example](http://plnkr.co/edit/J73HtVH71PnlUKfcRKwj?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `$parent.$index` instead of `$index` in

```
<tr ng-repeat='row in table.row'>
    <td ng-click="showIndex(field.name, $parent.$index)" ng-repeat='field in row.fields'>{{field.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('App', []);

app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.table = {
row: [{
  fields: [{
    title: "Your name",
    name: "John",
    id: 'name'
  }, {
    title: "Your second name",
    name: "Doe",
    id: 'secondName'
  }, {
    title: "Your age",
    name: 26,
    id: 'age'
  }, {
    title: "Your sex",
    name: "Male",
    id: 'sex'
  }]
}, {
  fields: [{
    title: "Your name",
    name: "Kevin",
    id: 'name'
  }, {
    title: "Your second name",
    name: "Parker",
    id: 'secondName'
  }, {
    title: "Your age",
    name: 32,
    id: 'age'
  }, {
    title: "Your sex",
    name: "Male",
    id: 'sex'
  }]
}, {
  fields: [{
    title: "Your name",
    name: "Barbara",
    id: 'name'
  }, {
    title: "Your second name",
    name: "Streisand",
    id: 'secondName'
  }, {
    title: "Your age",
    name: 60,
    id: 'age'
  }, {
    title: "Your sex",
    name: "Female",
    id: 'sex'
  }]
}, {
  fields: [{
    title: "Your name",
    name: "Linda",
    id: 'name'
  }, {
    title: "Your second name",
    name: "Lorry",
    id: 'secondName'
  }, {
    title: "Your age",
    name: 20,
    id: 'age'
  }, {
    title: "Your sex",
    name: "Female",
    id: 'sex'
  }]
}]
  };

  $scope.showIndex = function(name, index) {
$scope.showResult = name + ' in the row number ' + index;
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="App">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="Ctrl">

 <table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th ng-repeat='header in table.row[0].fields'>{{header.title}}</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <tr ng-repeat='row in table.row'>
    <td ng-click="showIndex(field.name, $parent.$index)" ng-repeat='field in row.fields'>{{field.name}}</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>

  <br>
  <b>{{showResult}}</b>
 </body>
</html>
```